# Can I download .php file from http://www.example.com/example.php

Tags: php, download

I have created a file download system with php. I created like that

```
phpfiledownload.php
--------------------

<?php 
$file = 'testing.php'; 
if (file_exists($file)) {
  header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
  header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
  header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($file));
  header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
  header('Expires: 0');
  header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
  header('Pragma: public');
  header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
  ob_clean();
  flush();
  readfile($file);
  exit; 
} ?>
```

And I also created `testing.php` file like the following

```
testing.php
------------
<?php echo "Hello World"; ?>
```

When I run `phpfiledownload.php` form my localhost I got `testing.php` file.

But when I change `testing.php` to `http://www.anotherdomain.com/example.php` in `phpfiledownload.php` I can't download `http://www.anotherdomain.com/example.php`.

So, how I can got `http://www.anotherdomain.com/example.php` via my phpfiledownload.php

Comment: Sorry, I'm not clear on what it is you want to do. Could you clarify?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To download `http://www.example.com/example.php` you can use the code below

```
file_put_contents("example.php", fopen("http://www.example.com/example.php", 'r'));
```

**Note:** If example.php contains php code it will run on the webserver and return the HTML output to you. So your file be the output of example.php and not the source code.

Comment: your browser/client application cannot display php source code as the webserver will process the php and display only the html output

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not very clear: are you meaning to download the php file or the result processed by the web server?

In your code, "testing.php" is a local file, while "http://www.example.com/example.php" is an URL.

In the first case your local web server fetches the local file and return it using the appropriate headers.

In the second case you obtain only the html output produced by the web server of the site "http://www.example.com"

Comment: Yes the first I download success is my local php file and second one is from url I want to got second one php file not html output I want php source code.

Comment: You cannot get the php source in this way: through your http/https call you are _asking_ to a web server to _process_ the php file and give you the corresponding *html result*. You can retrieve a php source through ftp/sftp (given that you have an account on the server). See the drawing here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_web_page

Answer (score 0):

> **Tip**
>
> A URL can be used as a filename with this function if the [fopen
>   wrappers](http://www.php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.allow-url-fopen) have been enabled. See [fopen()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php) for more details on how to
>   specify the filename. See the [Supported Protocols and Wrappers](http://www.php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php) for
>   links to information about what abilities the various wrappers have,
>   notes on their usage, and information on any predefined variables they
>   may provide.

Taken from PHP Manual, [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php).

Comment: I like Supported Protocols and Wrappers